# Beautiful emptiness

Tags: riddle, rhyme

To the world I am an oyster for it is my pearl.

My name is given to the most flamboyant of girls.

I travel a lot but not awfully well

since I can only fit in Hilbert's hotel.

I am always on the move, yet my waistline keeps expanding.

Being studied by scholars is quiet demanding.

What am I?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you

> The universe?

To the world I am an oyster for it is my pearl.

> The universe envelops the world.

My name is given to the most flamboyant of girls.

> Mrs. universe :)

I travel a lot but not awfully well

> Travels tremendous distances everyday but in every directions and without knowing where it's going.

since I can only fit in Hilbert's hotel.

> [Hilbert's hotel paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_paradox_of_the_Grand_Hotel) is simply put a concept of a hotel that can accommodate an infinity of guests. Therefore suitable for the universe.

I am always on the move, yet my waistline keeps expanding.

> Have been ever growing since the big bang.

Being studied by scholars is quiet demanding.

> Astrologist

Comment: The universe can fit in the multiverse :P

Comment: @boboquack you watch CW too much :P

Comment: Every line is correct except line 4, however, the answer is universe.

Comment: Now you are 100% right.  Good job.

Comment: @Supersolver Thanks for the nice puzzle. Keep them coming :P